# Event order guarantees in presence of concurrent methods calls

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition

```
class server {
    private Vector<Msg> v = new ...
    ...
    public void deliver(Msg msg) {
       ...
       v.add(msg);
    }
}

class client {
    private server s = server.getInstance(); // singleton
    ...
    public void propose() {
       s.deliver(new Msg( ... ));
    }
}
```

If multiple concurrent clients pass a value (`Msg` object) to a server by means of a [non-synchronized!] `deliver` method, is it feasible to assume that whatever client calls [or, more precisely, enters] `deliver` first will store its value first in `v` – or is making `deliver` synchronized mandatory to make this assumption hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot make such assumption because the scheduler can interrupt current thread that is inside `deliver()` but haven't yet made it to `v.add(msg)`. Scheduler switches to another thread that calls `deliver()` (afterwards) but manages to finish the whole `deliver()` invocation.

If you synchronize `deliver()` method, it won't prevent the scheduler from interrupting the execution in the meantime. But no other thread will be capable of entering that method while the first thread holds the lock si eventually the scheduler will wake up the original thread and let him finish.

BTW [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) is quite ancient, there are better alternatives.

Comment: Well, for the latter part: the `server` instance is actually accessing a `ConcurrentHashMap` - and notifies local worker threads to deal with newly added values ...but for the sake of simplicity, I chose `Vector` in my example - since it's "synchronized-by-design" (and doesn't add another level of complexity to the question). [Admittedly, the "level of complexity" of my question wasn't that high in the first place ...as it turns out.]

Answer (score 1):

If the server is multi-threaded, then if deliver is not synchronized, then it is not guaranteed that the first message received will be added first.